# "Writing generate-component-builder plugins" fails on JSS app build

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk

There is a NextJS + React + JSS app. After upgrading to the latest JSS version (21.4.0 ATM) and installing [Multisite](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/the-next-js-multisite-add-on.html) plugin, the following error appeared on build:

```
Writing generate-component-builder plugins to C:\app\scripts\temp\generate-component-builder-plugins.ts
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\app\scripts\temp\generate-component-builder-plugins.ts'
```

Looks like the file cannot be created. Works well locally. Previously, other files were generated in `/temp`, but the error did not appear.

Comment: check that temp folder is present

Comment: How did you add the plugin? What command are you using to build?

Comment: Temp folder contains committed 'GraphQLIntrospectionResult.json' file so yes, it is present. To add a plugin I created an app using `nextjs-multisite` plugin and merged with my current app. Can run it as `start:connected` or `start:production` (or just perform `yarn build`). Site resolving works perfectly fine in local Docker setup. Issue appears during deployment to k8s.

Comment: I also tried to commit the generated file (for the sake of testing) and received another error which states that the file is here but cannot be open: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\app\src\temp\componentBuilder.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 ways how to solve it.

1. (Unacceptable). Run rendering container as admin. Added to the rendering Dockerfile:

   ```
   USER ContainerAdministrator
   ```
2. Upgrading to the latest JSS brought two new records in the `/scripts/generate-plugins.ts` file (the first two):

   ```
   const pluginDefinitions: PluginDefinition[] = [
   {
     distPath: 'scripts/temp/generate-component-builder-plugins.ts',
     rootPath: 'scripts/generate-component-builder/plugins',
     moduleType: ModuleType.ESM,
   },
   {
     distPath: 'scripts/temp/config-plugins.ts',
     rootPath: 'scripts/config/plugins',
     moduleType: ModuleType.ESM,
   },
   {
     distPath: 'src/temp/sitemap-fetcher-plugins.ts',
     rootPath: 'src/lib/sitemap-fetcher/plugins',
     moduleType: ModuleType.ESM,
   },
   ...
   ```

   I noticed that all the old records `distPath` values were located under `/src` so I changed `distPath: 'scripts/temp/...` to `distPath: 'src/temp/...`. The error has gone...